# Cannot resolve symbol 'ButtonBuilder'

Tags: java, javafx

Помогите разобраться, изучаю JavaFX, в книге с примерами есть пример по добавлению кнопок, но весь код разбит на части, после его изучения и сборки идея выдает ошибку с текстом **Cannot resolve symbol 'ButtonBuilder'**, такой же случай с **scane** - в коде выделено так (** причина ошибки **) Сами кнопки созданы, обработчик событий прописан, в чем причина недогоняю, вот сам недокод

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Бухгалтерия");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 375));

        Button btn;
        btn = new Button();
        btn.setLayoutX(20);
        btn.setLayoutY(20);
        btn.setText("Тестировать свойства");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Свойства, унаследованные от класса Node:"+"\n"+
                        "Свойство blendMode: "+btn.blendModeProperty().getValue()+"\n"+
                        "Свойство boundsInLocal: "+btn.boundsInLocalProperty().getValue()+"\n");
            }
        });
        Button btnON;
        btnON = **ButtonBuilder**.create().build();
        btnON.setLayoutX(20);
        btnON.setLayoutY(150);
        btnON.setText("Установить свойства");
        btnON.setStyle("-fx-font: bold italic 12pt Arial;-fx-text-fill: #660000;
                -fx-background-color: #ff99ff; -fx-border-width: 3px; -fx-border-radius: 30;
        -fx-background-radius: 30;-fx-border-color: #660066;" );
        btnON.setPrefSize(200,30);
        btnON.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                btn.setBlendMode(BlendMode.DARKEN);
                javafx.scene.shape.Circle clip=new javafx.scene.shape.Circle(75,53,80);
// btn.setClip(clip);
                btn.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
                DropShadow effect=new DropShadow();
                effect.setOffsetX(10);
                effect.setOffsetY(10);
                btn.setEffect(effect);
//btn.setManaged(false);
//btn.setMouseTransparent(true);
                btn.setOpacity(0.5);
                btn.setRotate(10);
                btn.setLayoutX(80);
                btn.setScaleX(1.8);
                btn.setLayoutY(170);
                btn.setTranslateZ(-50);
                btn.setPrefSize(150,100);
                btn.setTooltip(new Tooltip
                        ("Это кнопка тестирования свойств класса Button"));
                Image im=new Image(this.getClass().getResource("image.png").toString());
                ImageView imv=new ImageView(im);
                imv.setFitHeight(50);
                imv.setFitWidth(50);
                btn.setGraphic(imv);
                btn.setStyle("-fx-font: bold italic 10pt Helvetica;");
//btn.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD,
// FontPosture.ITALIC, 10));
                btn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                btn.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
                btn.setUnderline(true);
                btn.setWrapText(true);
//btn.setCancelButton(true);
//btn.toBack();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btnON);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(**scene**);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: простите не scane, а scene

Comment: Класс `ButtonBuilder` не проимпортирован

Comment: @AntonShchyrov подскажи плиз, я так понял надо прописать 
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
но такой ипморт не найден, а просто Button у меня и такпрописан

Comment: А вы установили javafx?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, читал, что JavaFX должны были включить в JDK10, поэтому не установил, сейчас поставлю (стыдно то как...........)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а я тут задумался, если у меня все другие библиотеки JavaFX подтянулись, значит стоит

Comment: Зачем вам вообще билдер для создания кнопки, весьма специфичная вещь, половина билдеров вроде вообще устаревшими аннотирона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам следует прочитать до конца главы (или убедиться в правильности набора данного кода), т.к. довольно таки странные вещи делаются в нем. В противном случае, если на этом пример закончен и вы все верно набрали, то осмелюсь поставить под сомнение данную книгу.

Добавление импорта решит проблему с [`ButtonBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBuilder.html). На текущий момент является устаревшим, к использованию не рекомендуется. (уточните какую jdk вы используете и какую openJFX - в случае ее использования)

```
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
```

Строка `Button btn;` должна быть заменена на `final Button btn;` (это явная ошибка, и о ней должно быть написано, либо предложено исправить это самостоятельно)

Приведенная в коде строка `primaryStage.setScene(scene);` в принципе лишена смысла, т.к.:

1. такой переменной даже не объявлено
2. Установка сцены уже производилась в третьей строке метода

Что делать со следующими двумя строками подсказать не могу, т.к. недостаточно информации (что в `sample.fxml`; имеется ли контроллер; если да, то как именно он описан). Но в чистом виде в этом коде использовать их нельзя:

```
root.getChildren().add(btnON);
root.getChildren().add(btn);
```